# How to resolve the "ReferenceError: Office is not defined" when debugging with VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, office365, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I try to debug my Outlook Web Add-in that normally runs well under Visual Studio. But the same project throws error when run in VS Code. I understand that I have to point to an Office reference somehow, somewhere?

As far as I can tell, I have referenced the:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my Login.html file

This is my **Login.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var messageBanner;

    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
    });
    };
 })();
```

> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:44392/d1234530-8653-45d8-8634-b28355329cee For help,
>   see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached.
>   c:\Users\mydir Workplace\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5
>   Office.initialize = function (reason) { ^
>
> ReferenceError: Office is not defined at
>   c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5:5 at Object.
>   (c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:109:3) at
>   Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:14) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32) at
>   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12) at
>   startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) at bootstrapNodeJSCore
>   (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) Waiting for ReferenceError: Office
>   is not defined Login.js:5 at
>   c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:5:5 at Object.
>   (c:\Users\mydir\src\MyAddIn\MyAddInWeb\Login.js:109:3) at
>   Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:698:14) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32) at
>   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3) at
>   Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12) at
>   startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) at bootstrapNodeJSCore
>   (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) the debugger to disconnect...